# How to use glog in third party (C++ program)? I have added it in CMakeLists.txt but there still be file not found

Tags: c++, cmake

CMakeLists.txt in the project source path:

[image]

The fatal error (fatal error: glog/logging.h: No such file or directory):

[image]

How to correctly include it as header file? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Normally I use find_package() and build the third party libraries separately for help we probably need to see your CMakeLists.txt as text and not part of it as a picture.

Comment: Could you edit your question adding the target_link_librairies() you use to link your project with glog ?

Comment: BTW its against site policy to upload images of text: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used GLOG but I guess it is similiar to Boost:

```
set(find_package(Boost REQUIRED))
find_package(Boost 1.75.0 COMPONENTS program_options filesystem REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
  target_link_libraries( PhysGeo_lib PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
else()
  message("'Boost' can not be located on this machine!")
endif()
```

and then just include proper header files:

//  Boost

```
#include <boost/program_options/option.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/parsers.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>

#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
```